# jqplot: Zooming beyond is creating grid with same number multiple times

Tags: zooming, jqplot

I just want to check if there is any easy way to limit zooming. If I zoom beyond certain point, the axis look wired.

[image: Find the x and y axis ticks are repeating.]

Is there any way to fix or limit the zooming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its with the JavaScript itself we cannot control it and it will be hard to get a reference to that axises even. It's logical to render the same value the limit.